# Sass function that changes font color based on device screen

Tags: css, sass, mixins

I am looking to find a way to create a sass function that alters the color of my font from white (on desktop) to black (on tablet and mobile). The reason being is that I am overlaying text on a video on desktop, but then on mobile the overlayed text switches to blocked text placed underneath the video, so the font color needs to change to black at that time.

I am relatively new to sass, but so far have tried this as a mixin (that did not work)

** I know this can be done with css but am looking to make this a bit more dynamic and reusable **

```
$color-media-sizes: (
"max1024": #000 or #fff,
 null: #000 or #fff
);
```

with this function

```
@function color($mobile-color, $desktop-color){
    @return ($mobile-color $desktop-color)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried a media queries?

Comment: Yes! I know I can do this with media queries, but as the video will change in the future I would like a function so that minimal change is requires. But if media queries is the simplest solution I will just do that then.

Comment: What about media queries in mixin/function?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you really need to use SASS for this, CSS will do the trick.
Just put media queries and colors based on your device screen 
(Source : https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488)

Read this doc, it'll help you to understand media queries : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

```css
/* 
  ##Device = Desktops
  ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops
*/

@media (min-width: 1281px) {

/* CSS */

}

/* 
  ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
  ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
*/

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

/* CSS */

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

/* CSS */

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {

/* CSS */

}

/* 
  ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
*/

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

/* CSS */

}

/* 
  ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 320px to 479px
*/

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

/* CSS */

}
```

Mixin in SASS is like to create a "template" of a component. E.g. : A button

```
@mixin button($text, $background) {
     background: $background;       
     border-radius: 10px;
     color: $text;                 
     padding: 0 15px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

// Then you can call it this way :
.success-button {
    @include button("#FFF", "#0F0");
}
.error-button {
    @include button("#FFF", "#F00");
}
```

Hope I could help

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do that using just css media queries :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 980px) {
  body {
    color: red;
  }
}
@media screen  and (max-width: 979px) {
  body {
    color: blue;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  body {
    color: green;
  }
}
```